# Arduino - Ultrasonic sensor (SR04T) measure only 0

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ultra-sonic

I have a ultrasonic sensor (SR04T) that I have connected to my Arduino. I'm using the TX and RX port at the Arduino UNO. The problem is that it only reads value 0 cm. Could anyone help me find the error?

The code I'm using looks like this:

```
const int trigPin = 1;
const int echoPin = 0;

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{

  long duration, inches, cm;


  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);


  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);

  // convert time into cm
  cm = microsecondsToCentimeters(duration);


  Serial.print(cm);
  Serial.print("cm");
  Serial.println();

  delay(100);
}



long microsecondsToCentimeters(long microseconds)
{

  return microseconds / 29 / 2;
}
```

Comment: How many cm should it be (in your test setting)? Do you know that the sensor is working?

Comment: It is going to measure between 0 - 250 cm. I'm not sure it is working, I just got it.

Comment: Have you tried the fixes I proposed?

Comment: I have not been able to tried it yet. I will do it as soon as i have my arduino UNO and the ultrasonic sensor in front of me. I will let you know if it did work or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing two things incorrectly here.

1. You are setting pinMode in the Loop. No need for that. Put them in the Setup. You don't need to set pinmode continuously.
2. You are using pin 0 and 1 for your input and output while using Serial. Serial uses pin 0 and 1 for serial communication. Use other pins for your input and output. Have a look at http://marcusjenkins.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/ARDUINO_V2.png

Comment: I started with just changing the pins to 7 and 8. Looks like that fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know if there is any way to calibrate it? I did measure the distance with a Bosch DLE 70 Professional and there is a 2-6 cm gap between them.

Comment: Measure then compare, then adjust until what you measure you also get with the Arduino. You are receiving numbers from the input. Change your calculation until they correlate to the actual distance. Keep in mind that you are working with duration and that might also be off.